# Cannot set height and width using flutter_screenutil package

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I have used the flutter_screenutil package. But when I set width to a widget using ".w" and font size which is "18.sp" is not working.
Below is the code

```
Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.w),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text(
              "Sign Up to Surfyard",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18.sp,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                color: darkTextColor,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

In this, I cannot set the horizontal padding. "20.w" is not working and the following error shows

```
Invalid constant value.dart(invalid_constant)
```

These are the packages which I have installed

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_screenutil: ^5.0.0+2
  google_fonts: ^2.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `const` keyword as `20.w` is not constant

```
Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.w),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text(
              "Sign Up to Surfyard",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18.sp,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                color: darkTextColor,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

const means the field evaluated at compile time so can not be changed while the app working. .w tag is calculated whenever your widget tree has been built so it can not be const. Remove the const keyword and it will work